# Use Emoji as CSS Border

Tags: css, svg, emoji

I am looking for a way to use an emoji as a border for a HTML newsletter. Pretty much, I want the Christmas tree emoji () to repeat around a div. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You won't have much luck with many semi-recent advancements in CSS because desktop Outlook on Windows, since Office 2007, uses Word as the HTML renderer instead of Trident (Internet Explorer), so you're limited to CSS1 and basic features of CSS2, unfortunately. You may even have to resort to `<table>`-based layouts.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, one way would be to use the `border-image` property, which requires you to use a picture and not a character.
As pointed out in the comments, unfortunately this is not well supported in emails.

```css
.christmas {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 33px solid transparent;
  -moz-border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png") 33 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png") 33 repeat;
  -o-border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png") 33 repeat;
  border-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png") 33 repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="christmas">
  Merry Christmas!
</div>
```

[image: border-image]

Comment: Nice solution, but it is only supported in iPhone iOS 7/iPad and Apple Mail 6.5, according to [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)'s CSS reference guide.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with HTML emails so I was too optimistic. Thanks for the hint, I updated my answer with your comments.

Answer (score 3):

As you will use it for mail, a table will be the solution for you, like this

```html
<table style="width: 478px;height: 285px;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="height:30px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png); background-repeat: repeat-x"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:26px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png); background-repeat: repeat-y"></td>
    <td valign="top" style="padding: 20px;">

      Content
      
    </td>
    <td style="width:26px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png); background-repeat: repeat-y;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="height:30px; background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEaT.png); background-repeat: repeat-x"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with SVG text and masking. **No PNG**

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  /* our SVG's width and height is 30px, so we need to keep the width and height multiple of 30 to avoid cutting */
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  /* to center the text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='30' width='30'%3E%3Ctext x='50%25' y='50%25' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'%3E%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000) content-box, 
          linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
          mask-composite: exclude;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hello
</div>
```

The SVG that I use

```html
<svg height="30" width="30">
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"></text>
</svg>
```

I encoded it with [svg-encoder](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)

You can insert any kind of emoji:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  /* our SVG's width and height is 30px, so we need to keep the width and height multiple of 30 to avoid cutting */
  height: 240px;
  position: relative;
  /* to center the text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='30' width='30'%3E%3Ctext x='50%25' y='50%25' dominant-baseline='middle' text-anchor='middle'%3E%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  
  --mask: linear-gradient(#000, #000) content-box, 
          linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
          mask-composite: exclude;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Hello
</div>
```